# Alternative models for regression on category variables in non linear data

Tags: regression, machine-learning, python, scikit-learn

I want to predict the `Financial Loss` based on the `Incident Type` on this dataset

[image]

There are 80 samples altogether and this was what was visualised

[image]

I tried

```
enc = OneHotEncoder(sparse=False)
enc=enc.fit_transform(df2[['Incident Type']]) # [error,hacking,malware,misuse,social]
X = enc
Y = df2['Financial Loss']
model=LinearRegression()
model.fit(X,Y)

print('Loss prediction for error: {}'.format(model.predict([[1,0,0,0,0]])))
print('Loss prediction for hacking: {}'.format(model.predict([[0,1,0,0,0]])))
print('Loss prediction for malware: {}'.format(model.predict([[0,0,1,0,0]])))
print('Loss prediction for misuse: {}'.format(model.predict([[0,0,0,1,0]])))
print('Loss prediction for social: {}'.format(model.predict([[0,0,0,0,1]])))
Loss prediction for error: [7610027.70000002]
Loss prediction for hacking: [41912703.84615384]
Loss prediction for malware: [458333.33333333]
Loss prediction for misuse: [795703.]
Loss prediction for social: [21267679.99999999]

model.score(X,Y)
0.11545420819598817
```

and the model score doesnt seem correct as its only 0.1. I know linear regression is used when the re is a linear shape, and I chose linear regression as each category has the shape of a vertical line, or am I doing it wrong on this? What models should I use on predicting quantitative dependent variable using categorical independent variable?

Comment: [Does this differ from your other question?](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/99986/predict-a-continuous-data-without-a-linear-shape-on-data-points)

Answer (score 0):

Your model is learning to predict the average financial loss for each incident type, which is what you would expect if incident type is the predictor available to the model.

Perhaps you want to add year and employee count as additional predictors?